# EXTJS 4.1 , listeners for events on grid row body tpl

Tags: gridview, extjs, listener, onclicklistener, dom-events

Currently I am facing a problem in extjs, which is I have a grid with the feature rowbody.
In this rowbody feature I render a tpl.

This tpl is as follow:

```
.
.
.
'<tpl for="datalist">' + 
  <b>{name}</b>: </tpl>
   <span class="test"><em class="test1">{number}</em></span>' + 
'</tpl>
.
.
.
```

When a user open the rowbody there is another data and a part of it is that what I am showing, there will be a list like this:

data list: 111111,2222,3333.....

I need when a user click on one of those numbers to get the dom element get the number and fire a special event, so how  can I do this, without using dataview? I already implemented it in dataview, but it is important to have it inside rowbody feature.

Please do not hesitate in asking for any other information... I hope that this enough and you can help me.

Comment: THE TPL AS FOLLOW

.
.
.
'<tpl for="datalist">' + 
        
<b>{name}</b>: </tpl><span class="number"><em class="test">{number}</em></span>' + 
'</tpl>
.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a javascript onclick event inside of the template.

```
   <tpl for="datalist">' + <b><a href=# onclick=alertName("{name}")>{name}</a></b>

function alertName(name){
    alert(name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying but ...
ya i know this way, but unfortunitly i can not use it it will affect the application, i need to implement it in extjs way using their events and listeners.

so do u just a way for implement it?

Comment: In pure ExtJS, I don't know that you'll be able to get down to that level. At that point, it's just rendered HTML inside of a div.  You could access the Row Cell though ExtJS, using the [cellclick](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-cellclick)  event on the grid panel, access the row record inside of there, record.data.name.